# Trace speed issues in python running on google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, django-nonrel

I'm new to python, django and google app engine. All great tools and have been enjoying working with them.

However, on my production site its taking 4 seconds to load a webpage, which I think is horrible and needs to be less than a second. I've also verified the long amount of time is in the request to the get the page, not downloading any media files.

First thought is yes, it still has the first start issues any gae app would, I'm not trying to fix those. I understand that the first time you hit your website after uploading a new version it needs to load up the code for the first time. Additionally, if your site isn't visited often then this happens alot. All of this I'm aware of and not trying get more info on.

My site is relatively simple and its not loading big data or displaying complicated designs. And on my localhost it runs extremely fast. I should also point out that I'm using Django nonrel, which is a great tool that allows me to develop quickly with django on gae: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel

The problem I'm having is that its taking way to long for pages to load in production and I need to get to the bottom of it. I'm sure I've coded something poorly, but I'm not familiar enough with python and gae to know the best debugging practices, especially if it only seems to have issues in production.

**So for a newbie python / django / google app engine developer, how do I quickly and easily find what functions are taking so much time?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html).